# Fondo desenfocado y transparente en CardView Android Studio

Tags: java, android, studio, cardview

estoy tratando de hacer esto

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOCbc.png

y estoy obteniendo esto

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6ANa.png

no puedo hacer el fondo transparente y desenfocado como en la primera foto como hago eso?

cuando intento poner un alpha en el cardview, esto me afecta tambien al texto y hace que le texto tenga menos opacidad, como se ve en la segunda foto.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            card_view:cardElevation="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="For example"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:src="@drawable/imagen1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
            
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: puedes usar esta librería para el blur: https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry. El alpha es solo para opacidad

Comment: @armen pero donde y como tendria que poner el codigo? perdon es que no soy muy avanzado en Android Studio